Which SQL function can I use to change the zeroes values to Null values?
The station’s meteorologist has tasked me with understanding the relationship between wind speed and visibility in 2023. However, I am working with the newest data, and it hasn’t been cleaned yet. Missing values were incorrectly entered as zeroes affecting the outcome.
I need to Change them to null values before I look for trends, otherwise I won't be able to analyze all data available correctly
